# Android Notifications like WhatsApp

Tags: android, notifications

I'm making an Android application and I want to get notifications like in WhatsApp – as the message comes. If any updates are made on the server then a notification should come to the user so he can check the application. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to integrate [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) with your system, so application need to get sender_id from google and put it to your server. Then if you want to invoke notification on your app you need to send message using this sender_id.

[Here](http://techlovejump.com/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/) you can find nice tutorial. If you will have any question just give me a word.

I hope it would help you

Comment: thanks a lot...
i want to know do i have to purchase any license or gateway something.

Comment: Only thing you need to have is your server with script which would send notification to app and db to store this sender_id

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). With it you can send information from a server to an Android device. The Android device will be waiting for messages from the server instead of polling the server at timed intervals.